# PHP session without cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies

Is there a way that I can initiate a persistent session in PHP without the placement of a session cookie? Are there other ways of maintaining a session across pages, such as an IP address-based solution?

My reason for asking is, is that although most users have cookies on, I want to see if there's a way for a login system to work for those with it disabled (even though I think disabling cookies is just unnecessary paranoia, personally).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I don't think it's too much to ask your users to enable cookies. I find it silly when people turn them off entirely.

Otherwise, you can set your `session.use_only_cookies` to "0" to force the appendage of a session ID to URLs within your php. This approach, however, has several draw backs. Mainly that of keeping the state within the URL, as opposed to the Cookie header. If a user were to copy and paste the URL of the page they were on, and someone else were to click on it, they would both be using the same session.

```
<?php
     ini_set("session.use_cookies", 0);
     ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", 0);
     ini_set("session.use_trans_sid", 1);
     ini_set("session.cache_limiter", "");
     session_start();
```

Comment: I believe the OP wanted `session.use_cookies` set to 1

Comment: And it should be noted that these settings do not alter JS hyperlinks and Location headers in PHP code.

Comment: Indeed, who still browses with cookies off in 2010? While it's still possible, I doubt anyone still does this; and thus the question is rather academic. (Even the spiders can have cookies now)

Comment: "(Even the spiders can have cookies now)" Aww. :) I say let them, even if it gives them love handles.

Comment: Facebook apps run in an IFrame which, on IE, are not allowed to store cookies (default security settings)

Comment: You all seem to be blindly following cookies as a good thing. However, when using a proxy-cache such as Varnish, session cookies are horrible. They seriously reduce cacheability of content.

Comment: To clarify, certainly use a session cookie when you *require* a session, but avoid unnecessary use of sessions. Don't start a session out of habit. Remove the session cookie when you no longer need the session, and don't start sessions for requests that don't use it such as images and stylesheets. Many frameworks default to setting a session on *everything*. Avoid that behaviour.

Comment: Just FYI, it's actually a legal requirement in the EU to ask users' permission before storing cookies on their machines (although I realise it probably wasn't back when the original answer was posted)

Comment: @MartijnHeemels That's why you have to separate cacheable and non-cacheable content, and why the Vary: header exists.

Comment: @w43L http://www.marco.org/2007/04/27/p3p-sucks-how-to-get-frame-cookies-unblocked-in-ie6

Comment: ***"has several draw backs"*** That is not really true if you use IP checking on every session created. If the IP is not the same destroy session then you is safe. You will be able to share that url even with SESSION and no one would be able you get your session from outside your current IP. For mega sensitive data this would be a nice reading that includes other things tho make sessions more sercure and widely usable preventing hijacking http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-bulletproof-sessions

Comment: I tend to wonder what life would be like if HTTP connections were not as ephemeral as they are. If a secure connection were maintained at all times, we wouldn't have to worry about things such as session cookies and whatnot. Even re-establishing a secure connection when there's an outage is something many protocols do well. But, since HTTP and HTTPS disconnect after every communication, we have to worry about verifying that each new connection attempt is made by the same individual who connected the first time, a much harder task.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the ini-Value of `session.use_trans_sid` to true in order to activate appending the session id to every URL. Have a look at [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid).

For security purposes you should then limit the session to the IP that created the session. This is not perfectly secure though, as someone with the same IP (behind a proxy e.g.) could reuse that very same session.

Answer (score 4):

You can work with session IDs in URLs, and disabling cookies with:

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 1);
session_start();
// IP check
if($_SESSION['ip_check'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){
   session_regenerate_id();
   session_destroy();
   session_start();
}
$_SESSION['ip_check'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
// session stuff
```

Note: it's highly discougared to use session IDs in URLs. IP addresses can change when travelling around with a wireless card and proxy servers have the same IP address. It's easily broken when clicking 'an old URL' (with the old session ID).

You may also be interested in creating your own session handling function (in conjuction with a database). You would ignore the session ID, and bind it to the IP address. (see examples in http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Comment: Binding to an ip address seems a bad way to go.
Some (corporate?) users may be located behind a proxy, where multiple users can have the same ip adress.

Comment: @Leander Wooord! This can lead to very bad situations, where the entire company / family / student living complex has access to your user's account.

Comment: Here in Germany the largest ISP (Telekom) even got an own proxy a lot of people use. So in the worst case an hole ISP Network will use one account. This is really annoying as it makes it almost impossible to ban IP addresses if you don't want to rely on X-HTTP-Forwarded-For header.

Answer (score 0):

You can save session id per IP in the database:

Create a mysql table with three fields: session_id, ip and unique temp key (for logged users) or any other condition you like. Then turn off session cookies and use_trans_sid.

then make a code to manage session behavior based on this new table!

after `session_start()` save session_id in the table and later receive it from table (by IP and any other condition) and then call

```
session_id($in_table_session_id);
```

for more information and complete guide see: https://gist.github.com/mimrahe/77415f4a9e238c313bbe8c42f8a6b7fe

Comment: Again, this is binding by IP and not altogether effective, especially for scopes where multiple users share the same IP (eg. University, company or org proxys, etc)

Comment: @T30 The "for more information and complete guide see:" link is bad -- the poster is "dead".  Do you have a link for this?  Thanks.

Comment: Nope sorry, also a quick search on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org) doesn't give any result...

Answer (score 0):

You could create a database record or temporary file and check `$_SERVER` vars against the request on every page load.  It's a security risk, but with enough variables (have a look at the list [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)) you may feel you've gotten the chance of hijack down to an acceptable level; only you know how secure your app needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to do that then I would add the session id in the HTML code as a comment tag and use and configure the PHP code to use that session id which is included in the HTML code. I think it will be more relevant to do that instead of doing it with user IP or adding the session id in the URL.

Comment: +1 seems like a lot of work but it is definitely a workaround url-session-ids and cookies. maybe even more secure if you have a random string generated per form. combining the form's random string and a hidden session-id, you are almost certain an authorized user is making the request. i know ror uses something like this. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer on this is NO.  Using any combination of variables besides a cookie is insecure.

Think about it: when a user FIRST requests a page, the server is sending the page along with a unique value saying "HTTP is stateless, keep this so I know it's 'you' next time you call".  That means, that person, in that browser (regardless of tab), running at that time, has a unique token.

If and only if they've logged in successfully, that token can now be tied to a session on the server side.  Tokens are supposed to be so long and random that nobody could guess one in time.

Multiple browsers could be using the same IP address.  Multiple people could have the EXACT same user agent.  A cookie is the only storage system that works.

There's actually one more way, and that is to add the unique token to *every single link back to the server* as well as all AJAX calls, like `?PHPSESSID=my-unique-token-189481958` - but that's a pain to code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also login without Cookies only by Session Id and Time, but you have to write them both in your Database direct after Successful Login.

I have in index.php something like this that will always generate a new session id
based on time and the old session id if conditions are not verified.

```
if ($_SESSION['id'] != $row['session'] || time() > $row['sessiontime']) {
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id();
}
    
$_SESSION['id'] = session_id();
```

I use 2 variables in database for id and time.

And in login window I read the Session id from $_SESSION['id'] variable, then I increment the time and send both to database.