# How to save user setting on server side when cookies are off

Tags: php, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP session without cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740845/php-session-without-cookies)

Is there some practice to solve situation when user disable cookies and I need to store situation in PHP/MySQL server side and to disable cookie-based features?

Comment: Please search before you ask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740845/php-session-without-cookies

Answer (score 0):

With php you can put automaticly the session id in the url

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid

But this might be hard to use with dynamic link (like javascript).

You can link the settings with the IP+Browser...

HTTP is stateless, if your user want to use your site as an application (= with a state) they must enable cookies.

Comment: Ok. But in two passes I can`t know what IP (or Browser) was in first pass of rendering... Ideally I am looking for Class method for checking if Cookies are there...

Comment: @Dejan, you wan to check if the user enabled his cookies ?http://www.maheshchari.com/check-cookie-enabled-javascript-php/

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am skeptic for that function. I believe that for PHP checking for Cookies, application must redirect once...