# How to use $.post to be included in request of a new page

Tags: php, javascript, session, tracking, cookieless

I'm working on cookie-free session, I dont intend to pass variables through URL, but I try to use window.name or hidden forms. For window.name, I'd do mosething like this:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    if(location.href.indexOf(<my pages base url>) != -1){
    // the user is going to my site
        if($.parseJSON(window.name).previous_site.indexOf(location.protocol + '/' + location.host) != -1){
        // now I know, that user was of my site
            cookie_alternative = new Object();
            cookie_alternative.previous_site = location.href;
            cookie_alternative.session_id = $.parseJSON(window.name).session_id; // this is important
            .....
            window.name = $.toJSON(cookie_alternative);
        }
        else{
        // the user was elsewhere
            cookie_alternative = new Object();
            cookie_alternative.previous_site = location.href;
            cookie_alternative.session_id = <something new>;
            .....
            window.name = $.toJSON(cookie_alternative);
        }
    }
    else{
    //the user goes somewhere else
        window.name = '';
    }
});
```

So I can track session_id this way. I suppose I'd do something similar to this, if I was to use hidden input field. And now, I want this variable (session_id) from window.name to act as if it was cookies - user clicks on some link, which takes him to different part of my web => the request is sent to the server, server responds and page is displayed. With this request I want to send session_id to server using post (as if it was a cookie)- but I can't figure out, how to do this. I was thitking about something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $.post({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        data: $.parseJSON(window.name).session_id,
    })
})
```

but I don't think it's going to work, and as I said, I'm not going to use URL rewriting. Other way to do this would propably be to have some hidden form type post, click on link sets form's action (href of a link), sets data: session_id and triggers form's action.
Any ideas to send post to follow next pages request? Or how to use hidden form field to achieve the same thing? Any help really appreciated..

Comment: Can you explain why you're avoiding cookies as they can be automatically sent to every web request on your site and were specifically designed for these kinds of problems?

Comment: I'm not really avoiding cookies, this should be solution for users, who have cookies disabled.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740845/php-session-without-cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(e){

    //Preventing link from triggering
    e.preventDefault();     

    var elObj = $(e.currentTarget);

    $('#secret-hidden-form').attr('action',elObj.attr('href'));

    $('#secret-hidden-form').submit();
    return false;
})
```

At the bottom of your page:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['session_id']) {
    $sessId = $_POST['session_id'] 
} else {
    $sessId = uniqid();
}
?>
<form id="secret-hidden-form" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sessId; ?>">
</form>
```

Maybe something like this will work?

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do yesterday, but it doesn't work.. If you click on a link (a), a request (get) goes to server. In this situation, there goes one more request - form submit (post). And the result I got was always the one from the get request and sessionID wasn't passed. I could do one thing - delay the form submit to $(window).unload, but it's not nice.. There would be always two requests and the user's session would be 2x slower..

Comment: What I'm going to do is this: User tries to login, server checks his username/pw and responds it encrypted. Response will be saved to window.name, page will display user: username + links to his account etc and anytime there will be need of his credentials, it will be sent using ajax. So I'm going to use ajax with all forms and user-oriented stuff, but I wanted to do it like that anyway. F***** nightmare.

Comment: have you tried using event.preventDefault() ? Ill edit my answer to show the use

Comment: Ok, that seems to be totally perfect for this purpose.. I'll try it and edit later with the result.

Comment: Yes, that's really the way it can be done. Just fill hidden-form inputs by variables from window.name and submit this way. Still there are browser functions like refresh, back and forward, but these are rare and can be easily handled by using window.stop() and $(window).unload() - as I described above - functions. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can get data to the server with each page request via cookies, URL query parameters or by posting form data.

Maintaining a session across every link on your site without cookies will require a javascript override of every single URL the user visits on your site to either turn it into a form post with sessionID in the form or to add query parameters with sessionID.  How practical this is depends upon how many places on your site, you have to override things.

If I were implementing a session without cookies, I'd use URL rewriting (ideally server-side) so every URL in the page either all goes through a common JS function that adds the session ID before processing the click or just rewrites the ID into the URL so the normal click can just happen and it will have the session in the URL.  This allows you to preserve most of your navigation and server-side logic, but moves the sessionID from cookie to URL.  Of course, this won't be persistent from one user session to the next unless the user bookmarks a URL with the sessionID in it so users will have to re-establish a session everytime they come to your site.