# Will session work if cookies are disabled on client side?

Tags: php, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP session without cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740845/php-session-without-cookies)

If client has disabled the cookies, will session work in PHP and if yes how it will work? If not, what are the other methods to maintain the state of the user?

Answer (score 0):

Session will work with url getting appended with sessionID. This is alternate to maintaining session and is called url rewriting.