# php session variables without cookies

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I try to access session variables stored on a different page. When I have cookies enabled it works, but the session variables are gone when I disable cookies.

Here's an example:

```
<?php
//page1.php

session_start();

$_SESSION['startTime'] = time();

echo("<a href=\"page2.php?" . session_name() . "=" . session_id() . "\">Page2</a><br />\n");

echo("Session-ID: " . session_id() . "<br />");
echo("Session-Content: " . print_r($_SESSION));

// output:
// <a href="page2.php?PHPSESSID=ou1n4mrotvqc6dod41q8t0a432">Page2</a><br />
// Session-ID: ou1n4mrotvqc6dod41q8t0a432<br />Array
// (
//     [startTime] => 1339177944
// )
// Session-Content: 1
?>

<?php
//page2.php

session_start();

session_id($_GET[session_name()]);

echo("Session-ID: " . session_id() . "<br />\n");
echo("Session-Content: " . print_r($_SESSION));

session_destroy();

// output
// Session-ID: ou1n4mrotvqc6dod41q8t0a432<br />
// Array
// (
// )
// Session-Content: 1
?>
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I use session variables whith cookies disabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to change the php.ini setting `session.use_only_cookies` to `0` to allow the session id to be passed in the querystring. You may also want to use the magic constant `SID` instead of `session_name() . "=" . session_id()`.

Comment: Added `ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", "0");` just before `session_start();`Now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

By default, PHP sessions require cookies to be enabled. But, it can be done without cookies: [PHP session without cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740845/php-session-without-cookies).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your .htaccess file:

```
php_flag session.use_cookies 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The session ID is stored in the cookie. How else would the server know that it's the same browser talking to it?

(That's a bit of a trick question, since you can save session IDs in URLs, but that's not a good idea).

Cookies are used to store sessions. Without them, you cannot (safely) store a session.

Comment: Using cookies for your session ID is not inherently safer than just passing a session ID in the URL. I take objection to the "safely" in your post.

Comment: You are probably right that using cookies is a bit safer. In my case I just use the session to let hyperlinks expire after a few minutes. I think in this case there are no security issues.