# session ID passed, set, but session does not contains the variables (cookies disabled)

Tags: php, session

I have a problem with passing session variables with cookies disabled.

***Script 1:***

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['x'] =55;
```

then I pass the session ID via URL (I tried it both via chancing the php init settings and also explictely appending it to URL) for example:

```
<a href="abc.php?<?php echo SID; ?>">abc to</a>
```

***Script 2 abc.php:***

```
session_start();
session_id($_GET['PHPSESSID']);
echo session_id();
```

---

I check the ID in second script, its exactly the same. But when I try to use the:
`$_SESSION['x']` variable or to `print_r` on `$_SESSION` it shows it is not set.

Comment: [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740845/php-session-without-cookies), It will probably solve your issue.

Comment: unfortunately, I read that before posting this question and it didnt help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unbelievable. After hours of searching I finally found a solution only minutes within posting this question here.

The order should be:

```
session_id($_GET['PHPSESSID']);
session_start();
```

So the first the ID has to be set and then the session started. Or at least it seems so.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo session_id($_GET['PHPSESSID']);
```

instead of

```
session_id($_GET['PHPSESSID']);
echo session_id();
```

session_id() returns the session_id( string $id )
So either you store it in a $var or you echo it in my example above

Do you expect to get the same as you set with $_SESSION['x'] = 55; ?

Comment: now I am pretty much confused as php manual says that you can use it to set and get session id http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php After changing the code as you suggested now I am getting different ID and I cant figure out why.