# how to change cookie to session?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm new to session and cookie. Like the tile I want to change cookie to session. I just get code from the link here: http://www.pixelconnect.com.au/web-design-blog/php-css-theme-switcher-with-cookies?
I've tried some way but it didn't work.

before doctype:

```
<?php
$theme1 = business;
$theme2 = modern;
$theme3 = web2;
if(isset($_POST['style']))
{setcookie('style', $_POST['style'], time()+(60*60*24*1000));
$style=$_POST['style'];}
elseif(isset($_COOKIE['style']))
{$style=$_COOKIE['style'];}
else
{$style=$theme1;} ?>
```

head:

```
<head>
<link href="<?PHP echo $style; ?>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

body:

```
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post"> 
<select name="style"> <option <?php echo "value='$theme1'";
if($style == $theme1)
{
echo "selected='selected'";
}
?>><?php echo $theme1; ?></option>
<option <?php
echo "value='$theme2'";
if($style == $theme2)
{
echo "selected='selected'";
}
?>><?php echo $theme2; ?></option>
<option <?php
echo "value='$theme3'";
if($style == $theme3)
{
echo "selected='selected'";
}
?>><?php echo $theme3; ?></option>
</select><input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
session_start();
$theme1
$theme2
$theme3
if(isset($_POST['style'])){
$style=$_POST['style'];}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['style']))
{$style=$_SESSION['style'];}
else
{$style=$theme1;} 
?>
```

head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $_SESSION['style']?>" />
```

Comment: What do u mean by cookie with session..Do u mean that cookiee should destroy as session ends?

Comment: I mean, I want to use only session, not cookie. Change the cookie to session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the session instead of cookies, change your opening code to this (untested):

```
<?php
session_start();
$theme1 = business;
$theme2 = modern;
$theme3 = web2;
if (isset($_POST['style'])) {
    $_SESSION['style'] = $_POST['style'];
    $style=$_POST['style'];
} else if (isset($_SESSION['style'])) {
    $style=$_SESSION['style'];
} else {
    $style=$theme1;
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to destroy cookiee with session , just leave the time parameter blank  i.e

```
    setcookie('style', $_POST['style']);
```

would be enough...

Answer (score 1):

It's really very simple.  From PHP, just call [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

If you want to *disable* cookies for PHP sessions, just call [`ini_set("session.use_cookies",0);ini_set("session.use_trans_sid",1);`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740845/php-session-without-cookies)