# How to manage session effectively when you have a very complicated database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have one user portal account. I'm logging into it with two different usernames in two different tabs.

When I do a hard refresh `(ctl+f5)` in both tabs of the same user account, it opens in both tabs. That can be any username from those two. What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Session's mechanism uses COOKIEs. COOKIEs are shared between tabs.

If you what to login with one browser session by two differnet users you can disable storing session id in cookie: [PHP session without cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740845/php-session-without-cookies).

Also you can use feature of browsers. FireFox's Private browsing for example.

- [PHP's sessions. Basic usage.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)
- [PHP's sessions. Passing the Session ID.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php)

Comment: can u explain me why this is happening..??

Comment: i think when i do hard refresh or simple refresh it takes most recent session and change both different account to the same...??

Comment: @BhadreshDhanani, when you refresh page browser send cookie with session id. Browser can store only one session id for domain and path(/). When login action happens server can rewrite session id or use old session id for storing new auth data.

Comment: ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 1);
when i add this 3 line of code before session_start() it gives me error that ur session has undefined index

Comment: so whatever m doin like refreshing is meaning less..??
Means theres no way to solve it..??

Comment: @BhadreshDhanani, do not retail errors messages. Just print it.

Answer (score 1):

You cant login on same website on same browser with two different user. Better you use two different browsers.

Comment: gr8. How may I help how with that ?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to avoid session cookies.  Add the PHPSESSID variable to the query string, or have it in the path and use URL rewriting or PATH_INFO to translate `/x/y.php/925235a...` etc to `/x/y.php?PHPSESSID=925235a...`.  You can actually tell PHP to do the first for you.

Note, in order for this to work, you'll need to say something like

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', false);
```

or the like, in your script before calling `session_start()`.  Then PHP won't send session cookies; in most cases it will just transparently rewrite URLs in your page to include the session ID, so you get the first option for free.

The biggest drawback to this approach is that it makes your users vulnerable to an attack called "session fixation".  If i hand you a URL that already has a session ID, and you click it and log in to the site, you've logged in my session for me and i can now visit the site as you.  One way around that is to switch to a new session when someone logs in...but if your app is a shopping cart, it can be annoying making people log in to buy something.

Second biggest:  If a user follows a link that doesn't have a session ID, PHP won't recognize them.  (The user can use the "Back" button to get back to a point where they have a session ID, but that sucks usabilitywise.)  You have to ensure that the session ID appears in every link or URL.  Fortunately, PHP will rewrite most of them for you, but any links you generate with JS and such, you'll have to do yourself.

Comment: can u please give me link of examples about which u r talking...
m very new in PHP..nd know some standard rules