# how to code for users with disabled cookies and popups

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, cookies, popupwindow

Here's the situation: I'm redesigning our company's public facing website using ASP.NET, VB.NET and some javascript/jquery.  Some of the features I'm adding require page reloads (which register as popups) and cookies.  Works great if everything is enabled.  But I've noticed on some browsers (such as Firefox) I still get prompted to ok these actions, retain these cookies, etc.  Now I can code some contingencies for simpler pages for users who will not or can not enable these features, but I'd like to find a way to make it as simple as possible to enable the full features.  From what I've read, there's no way I can actually force it to happen the way you can force a browsers document mode by settings in the web.config file, but I am hoping there is some way to give them a button to click (or something similar) where it will enable what I need. Is there a way to do this programmatically? what I'm looking for is some code that will make the changes, instead of directing them to go into e.g. Internet Explorer security settings, which most end users find tedious if not incomprehensible.

Advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using cookies. Use Session or a database backend for things you would normally use cookies for. For popups, use overlaid divs such as [Ajax Control Toolkit Modal Popup Extender](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) or [jQuery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) instead of starting a new browser window.

But really, ASP.NET is designed to function with cookies. If you're users aren't using them, tell them they're penalizing themselves.

Comment: Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740845/php-session-without-cookies

Comment: @Diodeus That question is specific to PHP. This answer is about ASP.NET. Not really useful in this context.

Comment: @mason I'm trying to retain some information on the browser end so that returning visitors wouldn't need to enter additional information multiple times; I know session variables work better, but it's not an option if we want it to stay longer than the duration of their current browsing session.

Comment: Like I said, then you need to persist those values in your database if you don't want to use cookies. You can't have the best of both worlds.

Comment: Without cookie, how do you plan to maintain the authentication once a user login? Even if you use Session State, Session uses cookie to store Session ID. **Note:** cookie-less approach (using URL to store Session ID) was deprecated long time ago, because it creates too much problem. ***Basically, you cannot avoid using cookies in ASP.Net although you can avoid using Session State and View State in ASP.Net MVC.***

Comment: Well, I've got some database stuff going on already... I was just hoping to minimize it... but seeing as I can track logins by IP, I guess I can code most of it with SQL, and then just have a cookie value if they allow it which could reference the tables if needed... :/ not the answers I was hoping for, but I guess I can only work with what's available :/

Comment: **track logins by IP** - No @Jon, it is a really bad idea (even the MAC address is not a good enough). If a user is using private IP such as 192.168.1.100, you are automatically login to those whoever inside this Public IP; it'll open for a big security hole. ***Please do not fight with technology; you need to use cookie in ASP.Net.***

Comment: It's not a login per se.  It's just some customized information.  Nearest locations, stuff like that.  it's not actually giving any access at any point.  The real drawback to this approach is that people who come in from a private network may have IP's that change or overlap... but I think if I try and use the cookie, and if that fails, only provide generic information, I should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Certain browser features are ONLY user-configurable for security reasons. You cannot provide a button to change these settings because they would then not user-configurable.

All you can do is warn the user.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot change a client browser's setting due to security reason. Otherwise, all hell will break loose.

***Note:*** you can if you create an executable program, and a user runs on his/her computer.

However, you should never change a user's browser setting.

Instead you should give the warning and instruction to a user which is a proper way of doing it.

### Disable Javascript

[image]

### Disable Cookie

[image]

Comment: I don't think he mentioned that he's worried about users disabling JavaScript. Just cookies and popup windows.