# Passing session variables with cookies turned off

Tags: php, session

I am trying to pass session variable across the two pages I created. Cookies are turned off on my browser (firefox latest version), but I am getting an error. Here is my code

**index.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['name'] = "bob";

?>
<p>
    go to next page <a href="session.php?<?php echo SID; ?>">click here</a>.
</p>
```

**session.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

echo $_SESSION['name'];

?>
```

PHP cannot recognize the $_SESSION['name'] index and output the following error

*Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\S2\session.php on line 3*

Note: I have enabled the trans_sid on the php.ini file session.use_trans_sid=1

Comment: Is there a good reason you want to transfer the session id? Otherwise try it with out and post result.

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt Because he has cookies disabled?

Comment: Have you restarted XAMPP after updating your php.ini?

Comment: @Paulpro i just tried restarting xampp still giving me the same error. EDIT IT WORKED WHEN I TRIED IT ON A LIVE SERVER, I GUESS THE PROBLEM IS SOMETHING TO DO WITH XAMPP.

Comment: See my answer. I tried exactly what you did and came across the same behavior. I tried a few things and found a solution (here on SO btw) which worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your scenario and what worked for me was putting these settings **before** the session_start():

```
 ini_set("session.use_cookies", 0);
 ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", 0);
 ini_set("session.use_trans_sid", 1); // well you can leave this since you have it already in php.ini
 ini_set("session.cache_limiter", "");
```

I hope this solves your problem. Of course you can edit your php.ini too instead of hardcoding this.

What I like to add is that using trans_sid can create a security hole if someone gets your session id. Do some IP check before and limit access to only the IP that created the session id. Keep in mind that using trans_id can also break your app if using an old link with old session id.

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3740866/6622577

Answer (score 0):

One should definitely heed caution that **passing around session ids in URLs is a security risk and definitely not advisable**.

When setting `session.use_trans_sid` to `true`, which is what populates the `SID` constant, you also need to set `session.use_only_cookies` to `false`, otherwise PHP looks for the cookie first.

---

#### Reference:

`session.use_trans_sid` is actually a PHP 4 feature that, when used with a PHP build that had the `--enable-trans-sid` compile time flag, would transparently populate your relative URLs with the `SID` constant.

[From the manual](http://php.net/session.idpassing)

> PHP is capable of transforming links transparently. Unless you are using PHP 4.2.0 or later, you need to enable it manually when building PHP. Under Unix, pass `--enable-trans-sid` to configure. If this build option and the run-time option `session.use_trans_sid` are enabled, relative URIs will be changed to contain the session id automatically.

[Also](http://php.net/session.configuration#ini.session.use-trans-sid)

> **Note:** URL based session management has additional *security* risks compared to cookie based session management. Users may send a URL that contains an active session ID to their friends by email or users may save a URL that contains a session ID to their bookmarks and access your site with the same session ID always, for example.