# Cookieless Session in express-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, express-session

How can we implement cookie-less session in express js? Express-session provides a way to maintain session using cookies but what if we try to use express-session without cookies? Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a Express session works without cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42580911/can-a-express-session-works-without-cookie)

Comment: that won't work. I need a secure way to achieve this. In fact I could write my custom code to achieve that but I just want to know whether any package or library exists to do so.

Comment: The other method is to use of tokens JWT is another approcah

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not my requirement.

Comment: The most secure way to use a cookie based session but why didn't use it explain your use case here  i think this look like an XY problem

Answer (score -2):

I generally use token based authentication If I don't want to use cookies.

You can generate a jwt using username,password when user logs in send it in response.

When any user wants to view protected page he will send his token in the header, you will decrypt it verify the username pwd and allow him in.

You can also set timestamp for jwt,

You can use redis to save  tokens with expiry.